# Is there a better way to check for Virtual Directory and if not, Create it?

Tags: iis, scripting, vbscript, adsi

I have some vbscript code I use to set paths to virtual directories when a developer switches his/her environment to work on another project. Currently, we try to set the path, and if there's an error, we create it. It just smells funny. Is there a way to check if a Virtual Directory exists? And if not, create it?

```
set objIIS = GetObject("IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC/1/ROOT/SomeWeb")
objIIS.Path = strNewPath & "\SomeWeb"
objIIS.SetInfo

If Err.Number =  NOT_FOUND Then
    sVirtPath = strNewPath & "\SomeWeb"
CreateVirtualDirectory "SomeWeb", sVirtPath, true
Err.Clear
End If
```

This works just fine, but something tells me, there must be a better way. Does anyone have any suggestions? How do I check for the existence of a Virtual Directory? Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks for any pointers.
Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. Here is a slightly different approach I did years ago when working with IIS 5.0. I'm not sure if it would still work under later versions of IIS, but you may find it useful.

```
Function IsExistingWebApp(strAppPath)
    Dim oWeb

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Assume it does not exist
    IsExistingWebApp = False

    Set oWeb = GetObject( strAppPath )
    If ( Err <> 0 ) Then
        ' If an error occurs then we know the application does not exist
        'LogMessage strAppPath & " does not exist as an application."

        Err = 0
        Exit Function
    Else
        If oWeb.Class = "IIsWebVirtualDir" Then
        'LogMessage "Found existing web application " & oWeb.AdsPath
        ' If it does exist and it is configured as a 
        ' virtual directory then rerturn true
        IsExistingWebApp = True
        End If      
    End If  
End Function
```